# How to pass event into a debounce function?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, salesforce-lightning, debouncing

I am making a search on type Lightning Component for Salesforce.
I made a debounce function to check if a user stops typing, which does the delay successfully. However the function that runs in my debounce function will not accept an event now and a `console.log(event)` says 'undefined'. I am not sure how to fix this error. My code is below...

```
    debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;

        return function executedFunction() {
          var context = this;
          var args = arguments;

          var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
          };
          var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
          clearTimeout(timeout);
          timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
          if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
      }

    termChange(evt) {
        this.rows = [];
        this.searchTerm = evt.target.value;
        this.getCases();
    }

    handleTermChange = this.debounce(evt, function(){
        this.termchange();
    }, 2000, false)
```

When I used to just call termChange, It would search every key press and you would end up with duplicates, or unwanted records. Now with debounce it delays, but I can't find a way to pass the event in. (`this.getCases()` is another function I created that retrieves the records.) Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: have you tried by passing the event as a param in **this.termChange( evt )** inside the debounce second parameter

Comment: Can I get an example of how that would look, I am 90% sure I have tried it but not 100% sure if I did exactly what you said there.

Comment: I have tried this line      handleTermChange = this.debounce(this.termChange(), 2000, false);       If i try to put evt in this.termChange() it says evt is undefined, and if I just call it as is I get that termChange can't find target of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `debounce` function takes a *function* as the first argument and you are trying to call it with *event object*. Second, `termChange` is camel cased but inside the debounce call is is all lowercase, so this code would not run anyways.

Now, let's take a close look at what `debounce` does. It takes a function and then returns another function that expects the same exact arguments. So if you just do:

`handleTermChange = debounce(termChange)`

then you should get a function that would take the event as it's first argument. To be safe, I would bind it to whatever "this" you use in your example and then it should be good to go

Comment: handleTermChange = this.debounce(this.termChange(), 2000)  I have tried to use this line however it still doesn't work. Without it being this.debounce or this.termChange, it says the function is undefined. When i do have handleTermChange = this.debounce(this.termChange(), 2000) then the evt doesn't seem to get passed in, it says can't find target of undefined. Which I assume is coming from the evt.target.value. I can't seem to get around this problem.

Comment: Please note the difference between my line and yours. I am passing in a *function*, and you are passing in the *function call result value*, which will not work no matter what. You need to understand the difference between the function itself and calling that function:
*this.termChange* is a function, while 
*this.termChange()* is a call to that function

What you need to do is to take your original function (this.termChange), wrap it into this debouncing wrapper and then use that resulting *function* as your event handler - which is exactly what my line does

Comment: I just tried this, handleTermChange = this.debounce(this.termChange, 2000)          Now I got an error that says bind must be called on a function however, so maybe I am still not doing it right?

Comment: No, you are moving along fine. What often times happens with event handlers - they are called in a different context than the rest of your code, which means that at the moment when your event handler is invoked, the value of *this* is something completely different than you would expect. One of the way to deal with is is called "binding", for example: const boundFn = someFunction.bind(myContext) Now you can call "boundFn" any way you want, its *this* will *always* be equal to myContext. It sounds like you may need to bind your functions - just be careful what you are binding to which context

Comment: I get that binding is making a funciton constant across the problem, however I guess I am confused on what function I have to bind and how to accomplish it. I am assuming I have to bind termChange(evt) since that is the function handling the searchTerm and getting the evt. If that stayed constant then the debounce would work right? That's where my head is at least. Oh and thank you for being so patient and helpful, I have never had to deal with debounce or binding until today :/

Comment: handleTermChange = this.debounce(this.termChange.bind(this), 2000); I tried this, and it said a.apply is not a function :( Its got to be so close to *frustrated*

Comment: Before you just try to randomly bind anything to anything, please take time to *understand* your code flow and what happens at which moment in time. Then it should become clear which function needs what as the context

Comment: Well I know that the function fires due to the onchange HTML portion that calls the returned function from the debounce call. The debounce is calling termChange and giving it a 2 second delay, however I believe it loses track of the event which makes me think I should bind that. Then termChange calls getCases which pushes the results to the screen. I understand the flow at least I think. However I still can't seem to find out how to accomplish this.

Comment: I figured it out, I just passed in this into the debounce function as context and then it worked. Thanks for all of your assistance :)